# How to recursively delete all files from a given path except files with a certain file extension?

Tags: windows, batch-file

The answers I found on the internet do not work if the directory name has space character e.g. "Camera Roll"

I've tried to play around with the for/dir/findstr command but nothing seems to work

Batch file content:

```
@echo off
for /f %%F in ('dir c:\Users\melov\Pictures /s/b/a-d ^| findstr  /v ".jpg"') do echo "%%F"
@echo on
```

Mind you I replaced the DEL command by ECHO just so I can simulate the problem.

```
"c:\Users\melov\Pictures\desktop.ini"
"c:\Users\melov\Pictures\Camera" **(PROBLEM HERE)**
"c:\Users\melov\Pictures\ControlCenter4\Scan\CCF06182019.pdf"
"c:\Users\melov\Pictures\Saved" **(PROBLEM HERE)**
"c:\Users\melov\Pictures\Screenshots\desktop.ini"
"c:\Users\melov\Pictures\Screenshots\Screenshot"
"c:\Users\melov\Pictures\Screenshots\Screenshot"
```

Original folder structure

```
├───Camera Roll
├───ControlCenter4
│   ├───Email
│   ├───OCR
│   ├───Scan
│   └───SharePoint
├───cunha
├───Saved Pictures
└───Screenshots
```

I want to delete all files except the ".jpg"

Comment: Please include all relevant information into your question by [edit]ing it rather than commenting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd` has a default delimiter which is whitespace, so you simply tell it to change default delimiter.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s /a-d "c:\Users\melov\Pictures " ^| findstr  /v ".jpg"') do echo "%%F"
```

Similar principal using `tokens=*`

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /b /s /a-d "c:\Users\melov\Pictures " ^| findstr  /v ".jpg"') do echo "%%F"
```

Comment: no problems. You can do from cmdline `for /?` and you will see everything needed :)